# Стриминг с помощью VLC через командную строку

Tags: streaming, vlc, rtsp

Пытаюсь наладить потоковое вещание. Ввожу в консоль следующую команду:

```
cvlc "Sample.mp4" :sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=800,acode,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/rtsp}
```

В ответ появляются следующие ошибки:

```
VLC media player 2.2.1 Terry Pratchett (Weatherwax) (revision 2.2.1~trusty2)
[0000000001902a88] pulse audio output error: PulseAudio server connection failure: Connection refused
[00000000018eeed8] core interface error: no suitable interface module
[00000000018d2118] core libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[00000000018eeed8] dbus interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus session daemon: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
[00000000018eeed8] core interface error: no suitable interface module
[00000000018d2118] core libvlc error: interface "dbus,none" initialization failed
[0000000001902dc8] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[00007f8f90000b98] core stream output error: stream chain failed for `transcodesamplerate=44100:rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/rtsp}'
[00007f8f940009b8] core input error: cannot start stream output instance, aborting
```

Что я делаю не так и как мне это исправить? Переустановка vlc никак не помогла

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, стоит просто игнорировать эти ошибки. Если добавить к команде флаг -vvv, становится понятно, что все на самом деле работает. 
Видоизмененная команда, с которой все работает:

```
cvlc -vvv Sample.mp4 —rtsp-host=127.0.0.1 —rtsp-port=554 —sou t '#rtp{mux=ts,sdp=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8083/test}' :sout-keep &
```

Тест стрима:

```
cvlc -vvv rtsp://127.0.0.1:8083/test
```